# Importing PIL ImageFont is giving a py3 import error

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a PIL ImageFont but when I do that, it gives me the following error:

```
<ipython-input-16-ef225ec0d8fd> in <module>()
    ----> 1 from PIL import ImageFont

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py in <module>()
         27 
         28 from . import Image
    ---> 29 from ._util import isDirectory, isPath, py3
         30 import os
         31 import sys

    ImportError: cannot import name 'py3'
```

I can't find any similar issues on the internet related with this.

Comment: What version of Pillow you have got installed (`pip show Pillow`)? Try to reinstall Pillow (`pip uninstall Pillow`, `pip install Pillow`).

Comment: Facing same issue. Were you able to solve it?